# Sending FormData through 2 API's (NextJS)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, upload, next.js

So I'm sending some formdata, *including* images to my backend. To obfuscate/secure my backend even more - I'm learning that it's good practice to take advantage of the NextJS api (send calls from client to NextJS server/api, NextJS api acts as a middleman and sends data to backend api). I'm also using Auth0 - and the most secure way to get tokens is via the NextJS api itself.

I have no issues reading the data on my backend when I make an api call directly from client to backend. However, I'm having issues actually getting the data (primarily the images/files) OUT of the request on my NextJS api for repackaging and sending to my actual backend. I can't use FormData within the NextJS api either, so I'm just confused all around.

Client submit function:

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   const formData = new FormData();
   formData.append("title", brand.name);
   formData.append("slug", brand.slug);
   formData.append("bio", brand.bio);
   formData.append("logo", brand.logo[0]);
     const response = await fetch("/api/brands", {
       method: "post",
       body: formData,
     });
   });
```

NextJS api code (does not work - I am getting an access token perfectly, it's just the sending of the formdata/files I'm stuck on)

```
import { getAccessToken, withApiAuthRequired } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0";

export default withApiAuthRequired(async function products(req, res) {
  const { accessToken } = await getAccessToken(req, res, {});
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/brands", {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
    body: {
      title: req.body.title,
      slug: req.body.slug,
      bio: req.body.bio,
      logo: req.file,
    },
  });
  const products = await response.json();
  res.status(200);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing the "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" on the 2nd API call that you make. On the client side it's inferred from the FormData object, but on the server side you have to specify it manually. Altough, I couldn't find a way to do that on the server. This could indicate that the use case is wrong, I think making another request to your own server is a no-no. Next.js is meant to use this function called "withApiAuthRequired" as a wrapper, from which you call your services, or business logic. There is no need to make a second HTTP Request here.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "as a wrapper". Are you saying to set-up an NextJS api that returns a token, then just make the request right to my backend from my client?

Comment: withApiAuthRequired is a wrapper function, it wraps your action handler in a function that will handle the authentication for you. You may write your server endpoints as you would without the wrapper, but you wrap them with this function to authenticate. This funciton will provide you with the session data from auth etc. You can just call your services from the function which you have wrapped with "withApiAuthRequired".  Like so (your code goes after 'const session'): https://auth0.github.io/nextjs-auth0/modules/helpers_with_api_auth_required.html